# Are there any positive integers $n > 3$ such that $a_1^n+a_2^n+\cdots+a_n^n-na_1a_2\cdots a_n$ is factorable in integers? If not, then why?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know that if $n = 1$ then $a_1^n+a_2^n+\cdots+a_n^n-na_1a_2\cdots a_n$ becomes $a_1-a_1 = 0.$

If $n = 2$, then the expression becomes $a_1^2+a_2^2-2a_1a_2$, which is $(a_1-a_2)^2.$

If $n = 3$, then the expression becomes $a_1^3+a_2^3+a_3^3-3a_1a_2a_3$, which factors as $(a_1+a_2+a_3)(a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2-a_1a_2-a_1a_3-a_2a_3).$

If $n = 4$, I don't know how to factor it. I notice that if $a_1=a_2=a_3=a_4$, then the expression will be equal to $0$. So, I would expect something like $(a_1-a_2)^2+(a_1-a_3)^2+(a_1-a_4)^2+(a_2-a_3)^2+(a_2-a_4)^2+(a_3-a_4)^2$ to be a factor. I am not sure how to divide $a_1^4+a_2^4+a_3^4+a_4^4-4a_1a_2a_3a_4$ by $(a_1-a_2)^2+(a_1-a_3)^3+\cdots+(a_3-a_4)^2$.

Also, I see that if $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$ is equal to $b, b, -b, -b$ in any order, then the expression would be 0.

Similarly, for any $n$, I would expect something like $(a_1-a_2)^2 + (a_1-a_3)^2 + \cdots + (a_{n-1}-a_n)^2$ to be a factor of $a_1^n+a_2^n+\cdots+a_n^n-na_1a_2\cdots a_n$.

Why would $n=2,3$ in $a_1^n+a_2^n+\cdots+a_n^n-na_1a_2\cdots a_n$ be factorable but not any other $n$? Or maybe there is another $n$ such that $a_1^n+a_2^n+\cdots+a_n^n-na_1a_2\cdots a_n$ is factorable.

*I would like an answer that I can understand, without advanced vocabulary, theorems, or concepts like complex numbers beyond the basics. Please tell me if this is too much to ask for.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all positive integers $n$ ,such that the polynomial $ a_1^n+a_2^n + ... + a_n^n - n a_1 a_2 ... a_n $is irreducible over the real numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2165375/find-all-positive-integers-n-such-that-the-polynomial-a-1na-2n-a) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24a_1%5En%2Ba_2%5En%2B%5Ccdots%2Ba_n%5En-na_1a_2%5Ccdots%20a_n%24&p=1). Note this [answer](/a/2185611) there states there's a solution at the AoPS thread of ...

Comment: (cont.) [AM-GM Polynomial Irreducible](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h599342p3557426), with post #$4$ of the search result AoPS thread [Factorization](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1095524p4906419) also pointing to there. There are also other basic duplicate AoPS threads, e.g., [Multivariable Factor Theorem](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1195155p5849577), as well as related posts here, e.g., [On an identity with $n$ variables](/q/1182177), [SOS: Proof of the AM-GM inequality](/q/2244565), etc.

Comment: I am afraid there is no answer without "advanced vocabulary" or "theorems."

Comment: @NoChance, he’s asking if the polynomial is factorable, not the resulting integer. Also, $n$ is both the exponent and the number of variables (that way the polynomial is homogeneous), so your example isn’t what he’s talking about.

Comment: @Eric, excellent, thanks for clarification.

Comment: You seem to want a polynomial factorization, not an integer factorization when $a_i$ are integers in any event, I'd bet there isn't a factorization, in general.